# Vuetify datatable кастомизация шаблона

Tags: vue.js

Во vuetify я генерирую таблицу с данными следующим образом

```
<v-data-table v-bind:headers="clients.headers" v-bind:items="clients.items"></v-data-table>
```

Как мне кастомизировать шаблон вывода?

Пытался сделать вот так, но не работает, отображается так же:

```
<v-data-table v-bind:headers="clients.headers" v-bind:items="clients.items">
                        <template slot-items="clients.items" slot-scope="props">
                            <div>{{ props.item.id }}</div>
                        </template>
                    </v-data-table>
```